# Can't checkout other branch's with Git

Tags: git, gitlab

I was working on a branch 3, then in my team they started working on branch 4.  When I tried to checkout branch 4, I couldn't find it. The "git branch -a" shows me only the branch 3.

Any one have some ideas?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue I have occasionally.  Try first using git fetch to make sure you have a listing of all the upstream branches locally.

If you're having issues with fetch, take a look at your .git/config file in your local repo, it should have a section that looks something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = <repo uri>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Thanks? i dont now why it dosent work the first time, but it worked know. I have another question Why this issue happened ?

Comment: @medlamine Semassel Are you sure you remembered to do `git fetch` before doing `git branch -a`?

When you do `git branch -a`, the information that is listed is stored in your local repo (even the `remotes/origin/<some_branch>` entries). If you had not done `git fetch` since your colleague pushed the branch 4, there is simply no info about that branch in your local repo. It will only appear after the first time you do `git fetch`. And when you do that git fetch, you should see in the shell output that you fetched a new branch:
`* [new branch]      some_branch  -> origin/some_branch`

Answer (score -1):

I tried:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

Before and it doesn't work. I repeated it just now and it worked.

Comment: Updated my answer, double check your config file.